# How to extract this part of the string with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string

```
  var tabContents = {"1":"<div class=\"ProductDetail\"><h2 class=\"h2_style\" style=\"margin: 0px 0px 15px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; font-weight: normal; color: rgb(0, 102, 153); letter-spacing: 0.3px; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; line-height: 16px; orphans: auto; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: auto; word-spacing: 0px; -webv><\/div>","2":"","3":"","4":""};
```

Now i would like to get this part

```
<div class=\"ProductDetail\"><h2 class=\"h2_style\" style=\"margin: 0px 0px 15px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; font-weight: normal; color: rgb(0, 102, 153); letter-spacing: 0.3px; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; line-height: 16px; orphans: auto; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: auto; word-spacing: 0px; -webv><\/div>
```

So that part starts with `"1":"` and ends with `","2"`

How can i get the string between these two marking points ?

C# .net 4.5

Comment: That's JSON. Consider decoding it instead.

Comment: @pguardiario that is correct however i would like to use regex this time for certain reasons. so with any giving string i need to make regex behave that as a string and bring me out results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use capturing groups or lookarounds.

```
"1":"(.*?)","2"
```

Use the above regex and get the string you want from group index 1.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mD8iB4/2)

**OR**

```
(?<="1":").*?(?=","2")
```

Use the above regex and get the string you want from group index 0.

- `(?<="1":")` Positive lookbehind which asserts that the match must be preceded by `"1":"`.
- `.*?` Non-greedy match of zero or more occurrences of any character.
- `(?=","2")` Positive lookahead which asserts that the match must be followed by `","2"`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mD8iB4/1)

```
String input = @"var tabContents = {""1"":""<div class=\""ProductDetail\""><h2 class=\""h2_style\"" style=\""margin: 0px 0px 15px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; font-weight: normal; color: rgb(0, 102, 153); letter-spacing: 0.3px; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; line-height: 16px; orphans: auto; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: auto; word-spacing: 0px; -webv><\/div>"",""2"":"""",""3"":"""",""4"":""""};";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"""1"":""(.*?)"",""2""");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
```

Output:

```
<div class=\"ProductDetail\"><h2 class=\"h2_style\" style=\"margin: 0px 0px 15px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; font-weight: normal; color: rgb(0, 102, 153); letter-spacing: 0.3px; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; line-height: 16px; orphans: auto; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: auto; word-spacing: 0px; -webv><\/div>
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/q1O7KZ)

Comment: for example + is a special character. If it was beginning with + how would i make regex to treat it as a regular string ?

Comment: use `\+` to match a literal `+`

Comment: ty for answer. so for any special character i need to put \ before it ?

Comment: yep, you need to add \ before every regex meta character inorder to mach its literal form.

Comment: ok i tried first one. it worked fine but still included beginning and the end. so are there  any performance difference between 2 options ?

Comment: yep, the first regex includes the bgining and the end because you prints the index 0 not the group index 1.

Comment: ty very much for great answers. are there any list of special characters that i have to put \ before them to make them treated as literal ? or any certain function class etc at c# to achieve this.